# Android wear Accelerometer/Gyro sensor

Tags: wear-os

I am developing a application in android along with the Android wear support. While seeing the documentation from https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html, The following API's are available.

- Messaging API
- Datalayer API
- Data Sync API

I couldn't fine a reference for sensor API. How can i detect the sensors from the Smartwatch, either Accelerometer or Gyro?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use all standard Android APIs inside your wearable app: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html

Wearable app is just like any other Android .apk file, but installed on your watch.

Messaging API, Data Layer API etc are for syncing data between your phone and your wearable device.